# R: Make interactive maps that can be exported to HTML

Tags: html, r, maps, export, leaflet

I have been working with **Leaflet** for creating cool interactive maps in R. However, I cannot export the maps, as the background map ends up being grey after export.

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

m <- leaflet(data.frame(lat = 55.71654, lng = 12.47484))
m <-  addCircles(m, popup = "testpopup")
m <-  addTiles(m)
m

saveWidget(m, file="testmap.html", selfcontained = TRUE)
```

Is there an alternative to Leaflet where you can export your interactive maps as HTML? Or do I have to get into the whole Leaflet/Shiny thing?

Comment: I would say Shiny is the choice.

Comment: Updating from github did the trick for me `devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned my @Martin Schmelzer then it all works after updating leaflet through the devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet'). Thanks.